# Alllow one extra filed into serializer and return validated data with that field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know on this topic people asked a question before but my case is different and I have implemented almost all the solutions which I found but none of them are worked for me.

First I have defined three classes in models:

`models.py`

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ User Model """

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    agency = models.ForeignKey('agency.Agency', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    weekly_email = models.NullBooleanField()
    is_create_new_password = models.NullBooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    last_login_from = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    updated_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)


    """ The `USERNAME_FIELD` property tells us which field we will use to log in.
    In this case, we want that to be the email field. """
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]

    """ Tells Django that the UserManager class defined above should manage
    objects of this type. """
    objects = UserManager()  


class Role(models.Model):
    """ Role Model """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)  


class UserRole(models.Model):
    """ User Role Model """

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I have defined my serializer for user module:

`serializers.py`

```py
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializers registration requests and creates a new user. """

    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    agency_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='agency.id', required=False)
    role = serializers.CharField(source='role.name')
    weekly_email = serializers.NullBooleanField()
    last_login_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    last_login_from = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)  

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'role', 'user_id', 'email', 'name', 'agency_id', 'weekly_email', 'last_login_time', 
            'last_login_from'
        )
```

And At the end, I have defined my view file for user creation:

`views.py`

```py
class UserCreateAPIView(APIView):
    """ User create Api view class """

    #Allow any user (authenticated or not) to hit this endpoint.
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        """ create user using following logic. """

        request.data['user_id'] = request.user.id     
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(user=request.user)

        return Response({'message': response['user']['created'], 'data': serializer.data},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Now when I run it everything works fine like user is created, role is created as per my expectations. My view, serializer and models excuted but at the end on this line:

```py
return Response({'message': response['user']['created'], 'data': serializer.data},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I am facing error like,

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `role` on serializer `RegistrationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'role'.
```

Comment: You forgot to add `roles = models.ManyToManyField(through='UserRole')` to  `User` model.

Comment: The role field you mentioned in your RegistrationSerializer is referring to the default Django Role model, and not to your custom Role model.

Comment: So Pradeep can you tell me the effective solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use **ModelSerializer**

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

to

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

Comment: No man. It's still not working with ModelSerializer. I have tried it and it throws the same error.

Comment: After doing the above change I was facing one small error which I have solved and it works fine now and also give response data but it removes role field from the response. And I need it in response so can you please help me with that? If this will be solved then I will accept your answer. thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the code just now. can you please check.